# gem install sqlite3 on Windows errors out with "missing function dlopen"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have seen several similar questions about this issue, however, I also noticed that those questions are asked many years ago, so, as **a beginner** who got a feeling with Ruby and wants to "hang out" with Ruby on Rails, is there any short and easy way to **get started** with Ruby on Rails in 2019.

I'm currently **stuck** with the

> gem install sqlite3

step, this made me cannot succeed with the `rails new blog` command.

---

Error messages after executing `gem install sqlite3`

```
C:\Users\NguyenYou\Desktop\Workspace>gem install sqlite3
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Installing required msys2 packages: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3-3.27.2-2 is up to date -- skipping
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20190323-16220-14yansv.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out
```

---

Error messages after executing `rails new blog`

```
C:\Users\NguyenYou\Desktop\Workspace>rails new blog
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/NguyenYou/Desktop/Workspace/blog/.git/
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
      create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/update
      create  bin/yarn
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/cable.yml
      create  config/puma.rb
      create  config/storage.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/cors.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/master.key
      append  .gitignore
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
      create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  tmp
      create  tmp/.keep
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/.keep
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/fixtures/files
      create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/system
      create  test/system/.keep
      create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
      create  storage
      create  storage/.keep
      create  tmp/storage
      create  tmp/storage/.keep
      remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
      remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.6.0
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.2.1
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.1 (x64-mingw32)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.2.2.1
Using rack 2.0.6
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.2.2.1
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
Using actioncable 5.2.2.1
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.2.2.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.2.2.1
Using activemodel 5.2.2.1
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.2.1
Using mimemagic 0.3.3
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 5.2.2.1
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using io-like 0.3.0
Using archive-zip 0.12.0
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using msgpack 1.2.9 (x64-mingw32)
Using bootsnap 1.4.1
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using byebug 11.0.1
Using regexp_parser 1.3.0
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 3.15.0
Using ffi 1.10.0 (x64-mingw32)
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using chromedriver-helper 2.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.2
Using thor 0.20.3
Using railties 5.2.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using duktape 2.0.1.0
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.8.0
Using puma 3.12.1
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.2.2.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.2
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.3
Using tilt 2.0.9
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 3.141.0
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.0
Installing sqlite3 1.4.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r
./siteconf20190323-5992-z4mjhr.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... yes
checking for pthread_create() in -lpthread... yes
checking for -ldl... no
checking for dlopen()... no
missing function dlopen
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-config
        --without-sqlite3-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-sqlcipher
        --without-sqlcipher
        --with-sqlite3-dir
        --without-sqlite3-dir
        --with-sqlite3-include
        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
        --with-sqlite3-lib
        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --with-dllib
        --without-dllib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/sqlite3-1.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  sqlite3

C:\Users\NguyenYou\Desktop\Workspace>
```

---

I already have these installations in my windows machine

*ruby installation*

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x64-mingw32]
```

*gem installation*

```
$ gem -v
3.0.3
```

*rails installation*

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.2.2.1
```

*sqlite installation*

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06 bd49a8271d650fa89e446b42e513b595a717b9212c91dd384aab871fc1d0f6d7
$sqlite3 --version
```

---

I stored my SQLite database in the `C:\sqlite` directory and also added into PATH environment variable. Inside I have:

```
sqldiff.exe
sqlite3.def
sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.exe
sqlite3_analyzer.exe
```

(I've already reset my Windows OS and it's **absolutely clean**, and I only installed those things needed for getting started with Ruby on Rails)

---

I think I'm **missing** something but honestly, I don't know what is missing.

Comment: Do you have a compiler environment installed, like Visual Studio Express?

Comment: @tadman thanks for pointing out the `missing function dlopen` message, based on that, I found the solution at https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/248

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my issue fixed after running this command

```
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn
```

before running `gem install sqlite3`

---

Reference: https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/248

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and explicitly adding and installing v 1.3.6. (or the max version) worked for me. https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions/1.3.6 Here is the solution explained further https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35387. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

gem 'sqlite3', '< 1.4'

Add and re-run

This would fix the error

## ruby-on-rails

Answer (score -1):

First of all, uninstall the sqlite gem from your system:

```
gem uninstall sqlite3
```

Then, in your GemFile, mention:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

And then run `bundle install`

Hope it should help...

Comment: How does this fix the problem that the OP's C compiler environment is missing a C function? Surely, you would need to change something about the C compiler environment for that, not about the Gemfile?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest use this:

> bundle install --force

or reinstall like nileshkumar advised

This will reinstall all your gems, and possibly correct the problem

Maybe your problem is with your c compiler (mingw), try to re-install it

A good tip: the ruby/rails community always advice to not program in windows environment, there are a lot of problems with c compilation for rubygems with windows, if you can, try to use mac/linux, its way more smooth

Comment: still the same error `An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
succeeds before bundling.` because the `gem install sqlite3` did not succeed, the bundling cannot continue

Comment: @NguyenYou try to install mingw outside the sqlite installation and then use `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`